# Set Gesture Bar Color transparent [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to set the navigation bar to transparent, **but not hidden**. As in the example of Youtube Music on the left.

[image]

I tried it in several ways, whenever I define it as transparent the bar is white.

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
  systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  systemNavigationBarDividerColor: Colors.transparent,
));
```

Please see the image on the right. I just need the white part to be transparent, the gesture indicator needs to remain visible.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try but I think this should work

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.black,
  child: SafeArea(
    child: YourWidget(),
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that without using `SystemChrome` class. One way to do it is wrap `BottomNavigationBar` with `Theme` widget and use it's `canvasColor` property and assign`Colors.transparent` to it, as below:

```
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context)
            .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 0,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Above will result in something like this:

[image]

In order to remove the `shadow effect`, use `elevation` property and pass `0` to it, that results in transparent `navigation bar`, as below:

[image]

This way if you change your scaffold's background color, the nav bar will be shown in transparent color.

Hope this answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Put your navigation bar in a container.Then give no color to container it will automatically set color to transparent.To align Container to bottom you can do this.Hope this will work.

> flutter

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 50.0,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[

                  ],
                ),
              ),
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not enough alone. You should use below way also:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge,
    overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
```